# Restricting access to a page unless coming from a specific page

Tags: javascript, html

I understand that this question has been asked multiple times, however I need further clarification and a straight forward answer from someone that can help me please!

On my website which I host through weebly.com, I have a simple login page with a simple HTML script that is basically used to direct traffic to a desired page once they input the correct username and password credentials for their account.

Think of it like this:

Login Page (user enters credentials)
Crew Centre (redirected to this page if they log in successfully)

The reason why I am asking for a solution here is because I have an issue with users at the moment who are just bookmarking the Crew Centre instead of going through and logging in each time via the login page. Is there a way of forcing them to log in?

Does anyone know a HTML script (I would be happy to consider java-script also) that would work to block and redirect users who don't log in first? I'm after a script that would restrict users who don't come from a specific page (in this case its the Login page) and as a result they get redirected to a page which I will make saying "You must login first to access this feature.

I just want to reinforce that I'm not after anything secure at all, just something that is simple, this is just for feel and experience.

If anyone requires further clarification on my question, just let me know!

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using JavaScript on the login page to check the credentials. If that's the case, you could set a "signed in" cookie in the same JavaScript, then check for that cookie on the Crew Centre page.

You'll need to make the cookie go away somehow, too. Either set a short timeout or put JavaScript on the Crew Centre page to remove it.

Here's some example code:

```
// Put this in your login function, just before the redirect
var sessionTimeout = 1; //hours
var loginDuration = new Date();
loginDuration.setTime(loginDuration.getTime()+(sessionTimeout*60*60*1000));
document.cookie = "CrewCentreSession=Valid; "+loginDuration.toGMTString()+"; path=/";


// Put this at the top of your Crew Centre page
if (document.cookie.indexOf("CrewCentreSession=Valid") == -1) {
  location.href = "/Login.html";
}
```

Comment: James, thank you for responding. That sounds great, not sure on how I would do it. Would you like me to post the login script that I'm using if that helps?

Comment: I've added some example code, along with comments on how to integrate with your pages. Hopefully that helps :).

Comment: Thanks James, is there any further amendments that I need to make to that code? Do I just place it straight in? Where do I add the links for the login page, crew centre and the page that they get redirected to if they haven't logged in?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to change the redirect location, and you can adjust the sessionTimeout to control how often people have to sign in. Other than that, you just need to put the code in the right spot(s).